# What is the difference between .js and .ts files when creating a Selenium Protractor framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I am a beginner with Selenium Protractor. When I followed some tutorial videos on YouTube I found that most of them are using **.js** files when implementing test scripts. Unfortunately, in my real project the current framework is using **.ts** files instead of **.js** files. Can anyone help me to deeply understand the difference between **.js** and **.ts** files and is there any advantage or disadvantage when choosing one of them for implementing automation test script?

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/

Comment: Many thanks for your informative documents @SLaks. I will deep into it :)

Comment: I humbly suggest you should learn the difference between JavaScript and TypeScript. @SLaks has provided a link to TypeScript's site, which explains those differences, and the advantages of using TypeScript.

Comment: Think of them as two syntactically different languages, even though one comes from another. Roughly speaking, there is no obvious advantages OR disadvantages using either one. It's all about your preferences. Thus you need to work with both of them first to decide should you or should you NOT use any

Answer (score 0):

.ts files are translated into .js files by running the "tsc" compilation command, and the files that protractor is executing are the .js ones